# Retrieving business summaries using YQL

Tags: yql, yahoo-finance

I'm working on a project where I need to collect information about companies from various sources, one of which is Yahoo Finance.  It seems like YQL is the best way to get this information from Yahoo.

I'm able to retrieve stock quotes with a query like

```
select * from pm.finance where symbol="GE"
```

and relevant Yahoo articles with a query like

```
select * from pm.finance.articles where symbol="GE"
```

I need to retrieve summaries of businesses as well, similar to the information included on [this page](https://biz.yahoo.com/ic/10/10634.html), but can't figure out which table to query.  Is there a YQL query that will return this information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `biz.yahoo.com` domain has been deprecated.  As far as I can tell, this data is no longer available, neither through YQL nor Yahoo Finance.